# Page ghosting in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I recently purchased a Samsung SyncMaster SA550 display. The monitor works perfectly well, with the exception of Firefox. When I scroll through a page in Firefox, text and page UI elements become blurry and ghost for about a second either above or below the actual content, depending on whether I scroll up or down. I did not notice this with my previous 21 inch HP display.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Does it happen when you scroll up and down in another web browser?

Comment: Negative. Tested in Internet Explorer and chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the General tab in the Advanced section of the Options dialog invoked from the Tools menu, turn off the "Use smooth scrolling" setting in the Browsing section and see if that helps (you will probably need to restart the browser for it to take effect).

[image: Options dialog showing smooth scrolling setting]

This affects the following according to the built-in Help:

> Smooth scrolling can be very useful if you read a lot of long pages.
>   Normally, when you press <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, the view jumps directly
>   down one page. With smooth scrolling, it slides down smoothly, so you
>   can see how much it scrolls. This makes it easier to resume reading
>   from where you were before.

Comment: The issue still occurs after I have disabled the setting and restarted the browser.

Comment: Oh well, it was just a guess since I don't have the same problem. Be sure to turn it back on.

Comment: @Sean W.:  Another idea, try turning "Use smooth scrolling" off.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! I had tried that earlier, but I neglected to restart the browser. If you add that as a separate answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: @Sean W.: I'll just update this answer if that's OK.

Comment: @SeanW.: Weird, the Help file only says a restart is needed after changing the "Use hardware acceleration when available" setting.